# Formulating two non-negative variables without binary and/or big-M

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, modeling, binary-variable, big-m

There are two non-negative integer variables $q$ and $p$, where only one of them can take a positive value. To impose this relation, I write:
\begin{align}
q &\leq M(1 - y) \tag1 \\
p &\leq M(y) \tag2
\end{align}

where $y$ is binary and $M$ is a large number.

Is there a better way to model this relation, possibly without binary and/or big-M?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The big-M values need not be the same.  You should choose $M_1$ in $(1)$ to be a small upper bound on $q$ and $M_2$ in $(2)$ to be a small upper bound on $p$.

An alternative formulation is $p q = 0$, but that is nonlinear.

If your solver supports indicator constraints, you can write the desired implications directly, without specifying big-M:
\begin{align}
y = 1 &\implies q = 0 \\
y = 0 &\implies p = 0
\end{align}
But the solver might just introduce the big-M constraints on your behalf.

If your solver supports [SOS1 constraints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_ordered_set#Types_of_SOS), you can use those, but again these might be automatically converted to big-M constraints.

Comment: Is it correct to say that it’s impossible to do this using only continuous variables and a linear formulation?

Comment: Yes, because the L-shaped feasible region (union of two nonnegative axes) is nonconvex.

Comment: OK, I figured there was a nice compact explanation. :)